# A simple and free guestbook script?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, forms

Looking for a free, simple PHP guestbook script - couldn't talk the client out of the idea - and I remember using something fairly easy to set up a few years ago that used a simple txt file to store the guestbook entries. Does anyone have experience with any such script?

Answer (score 2):

Was it [phpbook](http://phpbook.sourceforge.net/) by any chance? It doesn't need a database. However make sure you read the warning - it's not being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I've been there, I empathize!

Take a look [over here at hotscripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/search/all-scripts/guestbook), the first three are paid ads for commercial products, but I can give a +1 to Online Guestbook Pro, HS have a decent rating system to help you out.